# Apply Value Converter on changed value in TextBox

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-8, winrt-xaml, ivalueconverter

I have a simple WinRT (Win8, .NET/C#/XAML) project. One of my XAML TextBox controls has a custom StringValueConverter attached, which formats a databound value from the View Model.

This works great, but it's missing one thing: when the user changes the value in the TextBox (say: a currency value) and leaves the TextBox, the converter should be applied automatically. So far the databound value in the View Model is updated, but the converter is not applied again by the View.

Is there any built-in solution for this or any known custom solution?

Comment: Is your ViewModel (which I assume is your DataContext) inheriting from the BindableBase-class (or in other ways implement the INotifyPropertyChanged-class)? You have to notify the UI that the value has changed.

Comment: Isn't this strange? When the user changes the value on the UI, why do I have to trigger the UI again from the View Model to update the (formatted) value? Doesn't (logically) make much sense for me. 

Of course, the View Model (resp. the bound data item) implements INotifyPropertyChanged. Otherwise, the whole databinding would not work.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your described scenario and it works fine:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ValueConverterTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:valueConverterTest="clr-namespace:ValueConverterTest"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <valueConverterTest:CustomConverter x:Key="CustomConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel>
   <TextBox Text="{Binding CustomText, Converter={StaticResource CustomConverter}}"></TextBox>
    <TextBox></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
namespace ValueConverterTest
{
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Windows;

   public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged 
   {

      public string CustomText
      {
        get { return customText; }
        set
        {
           customText = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("CustomText");
        }
      }

      public MainWindow()
      {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
      }

      private string customText;

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
      {
         PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
         if (handler != null)
         {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
         }
      }
   }
}
```

ValueConverter:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace ValueConverterTest
{
   public class CustomConverter : IValueConverter
   {
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
         return value;
      }

      public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
         return value;
      }
   }
}
```

This sample works fine. By leaving the textbox first the convert back method is called and than again the convert method.

Are you sure your binding works fine?

Comment: Are you sure this is a working WinRT XAML example? Looks more like WPF for me... And no: this simple example (adopted for WinRT) is NOT working in a Windows Store App project.